# Windows Media Service authentication issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2008

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 with Windows Media Service. At the client side, I want to use Silverlight to play the media file. I am using VSTS 2008 + Silverlight 3 + ASP.Net + .Net 3.5. I want to know how to implement a custom authentication protocol (I have a custom user database, which contains user name and password. I want to enable logged-in user to be able to play through Silverlight)?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use something like asp.net forms authentication.  Then you just put the media in a folder that is 'secured' by forms authentication.  I won't go into how to do that here.

In other words, your silverlight application lives on an asp.net web page.  If that web page requires forms authentication, no user will be able to view the Silverlight app without being authenticated.  Then, if you have your media in a location that is also protected by forms authentication, only users logged in will be able to see it.